Why are some types left uninitialized when default initialized while others are not?
I am a little confused by why built-in types (like int) are left uninitialized when default-initialized at automatic storage duration, while classes like std::string are not.
I read the following StackOverflow post: Why do uninitialized objects of built-in type defined inside a function body have undefined value?,  where it was explained that ints are left uninitialized at automatic storage duration to prevent overhead when functions are called multiple times. This is understandable, but why not do the same for strings and vectors then?
Is it because trying to deal with uninitialized vectors and strings could lead to much worse errors than trying to deal with uninitialized ints? That's the only explanation I could think of.

"could lead to much worse errors" I guess. Even destroying them would crash.

std::string, std::vector etc. are classes. They have default constructors and relevant destructors. int and similar types are not.

Classes have constructors that are used for initialization of the objects. Primitive types like int or double are not classes and have no constructors. With that said, it's possible to have empty or compiler-generated constructors that does nothing, and leave the object members in their default (possibly indeterminate) state.

I don't understand why constructors are being mentioned. You could make a constructor that doesn't perform any initialization.

The default behavior is inherited from C and basically applies to all types which are also valid C. C++ follows OOP principles, so a proper class with invariants (rather than an aggregate class) should always initialize its members correctly in the default constructor, so that the object can't be in an invalid state that violates the class invariants. The C++ standard library follows this principle. But C++ does not enforce this and still gives you the ability to leave stuff uninitialized (also in a class constructor) if you so desire for performance reasons.

At its core, C++ tries to not do more work than needed.  For built in types that means don't waste time and resources initializing them to some default value because most likely you are going to change it to something else.  Thus, no initialization unless the user manually specifies it.

@HolyBlackCat but if you omit required initialization from a constructor, you could end up with a crash in a destructor just as well - as you mentioned in your comment (e.g. if you have a pointer member). The point was meant to be that classes like std::string and std::vector etc. have proper default constructors.

@wohlstad I understand that. I'm arguing with "X isn't a scalar, therefore it has a constructor, therefore it can't be uninitialized" (which is how I interpret you first comment). :P Whether or not to initialize in the constructor is a class design decision.

@HolyBlackCat I see your point now.

In C++ there is this idiom  : "Do not pay for what you do not use", initializing may not be needed so C++ doesn't do this for you... unless you have classes with constructors that actually ensure some invariant is setup and maintained.

In practice there isn't much difference. Defining integer types without initializing them is rarely useful. Back in the olden days when definitions had to come at the top of the function there was some benefit, but now that you can create variables anywhere inside a function you can hold off defining a variable until you know what the appropriate initialization is. Seeing an uninitialized built-in type is a red flag.

One consideration is efficiency (the "don't pay for what you don't use" principle mentioned in the accepted answer to the linked question).
Another consideration is correctness.
User-defined types have constructors so they can establish invariants which they don't then need to waste time checking on every use.
For example, std::vector has a capacity, a used size, and a pointer. Those obey certain invariants (conditions that are always true), such as:

size <= capacity,
v[i] is valid storage for all 0 <= i < capacity
v[i] is a valid object for all 0 <= i < size

If a vector wasn't correctly set up by its constructor, it would at best have to do a lot more checking in every method, and at worst be impossible to use or safely destroy.
Now let's look at int. Every value from INT_MIN to INT_MAX is equally valid. No value is more or less possible to use or safely destroy. There are simply no invariants to establish in the first place.
Note that if you have an integral type that really has some invariant, you can absolutely write a class to establish this instead of using a raw int. That doesn't mean that every other raw int should acquire the same invariant.

A couple more notes on default-initializing primitives:

Some languages do initialize integers, for example, to zero. This does have some runtime cost that C++ has chosen to avoid, but not every language is trying to compete on execution speed.
This behaviour "feels friendly" at the cost of potentially hiding mistakes.

There is a proposal for C++26 to initialize some primitives to "erroneous values". This does have the same runtime cost but, in contrast to the above, is intended to make it very obvious that an error has occurred.



Except your claim about int that "No value is more or less possible to use or safely destroy" only applies to an initialized int.  Uninitialized one still is magic and unsafe to use.

Does the C++ standard allow for an uninitialized bool to crash a program? , after reading this you will never leave a variable uninitialized, ever

If we ignore the elusive trap representation, uninitialized int simply doesn't have any magic values that are unambiguously invalid. Compile-time UB tracking is orthogonal to the actual bit-pattern. bool is quite different in that respect.

They (vectors and strings) would be very hard to use correctly if they could be uninitialized.
Let's say the vector is designed so that std::vector<int> v; is uninitialized. If after that you do v = {1,2,3};, the operator= has to destroy the existing memory block, if any. How can it tell if there's an existing memory in the first place, if the pointer to it is uninitialized? You could now introduce a second kind of assignment (assign_to_uninitialized?) that ignores the existing contents, but this would be error-prone.
You could say that it's enough to zero the pointer but not size/capacity. This would work for the scenario above, but is still fairly error-prone.
What you can avoid initializing is std::string's embedded character storage (used for SSO). Famously, libc++'s std::string is faster to construct using std::string("") rather than std::string(), because the former doesn't zero the storage, other than setting the first byte to null.

That's a good explanation. In general the main issue is how to destroy/free an existing object if you are not sure whether it was initialized.

The simple answer is that some types have invariants.
An invariant is some guarantee about the data, such as "The size of a std::string is never greater than its capacity."  These invariants must always be true.
When a type has invariants, it can no longer have data that is completely uininitialized.

But the absence of (type-associated) invariants isn't sufficient to make an uninitialized variable safe to use...
